# I need to take the date from mysql database and print the difference between today and the fetched date

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, date

```
<?
foreach ($results as $data) {
  $date = $data->created;
  $now = new DateTime();
  echo $date->diff($now)->format(" %y years,%d days, %h hours and %i minuts");
?>
```

I used this code to fetched date from mysql table and print it in codeigniter framework view file. And my mysql date type is "timestamp". So can you please help me to print the difference between today and the fetched date from mysql table.
error msg-Call to a member function diff() on string -- and got this message after using this code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Comment: You can do this also in your mysql query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to convert your `created` value into a DateTime. The timestamp value from your database looks like `"2018-02-02 05:08:32"`. The constructor of `DateTime` could convert it. So, you have just to wrap your value using `new DateTime()` :

```
$date = new DateTime($data->created);
$now = new DateTime();
echo $date->diff($now)->format(" %y years,%d days, %h hours and %i minuts");
```

Comment: Thank you sir I corrected my error. Thank You very much

Answer (score 0):

you need to transform your timestamp into a DateTime object before you can diff:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimestamp($data->created);
```